# Create a Virtual Machine from php, perl, or python? Is it possible or has it been done?

Tags: virtualization, lamp, virtual-machine

I had this thought experiment of installing an OS on a php server over http.

So, what I am asking: Would it be possible to build a VM player (using the server's resources) from a server language like perl, php, or python? Or is my understanding of servers and security lacking in a way that would show this to be impossible?

Comment: Do you mean a VM player a'la VMware (ie emulating a whole machine) or a VM player a'la a Java Virtual Machine?

Comment: A machine that emulates a whole machine. So one could run desktop programs on a server. I know its a wild idea, but has it been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as outlandish as you might think.

UeberHacker Fabrice Bellard (the guy who created QEMU, among many other notable achievements) recently did precisely that.  He created a VM in Javascript.  That runs a virtual Linux system in your Web browser:

http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2011/05/pc-emulator-in-javascript-run-linux-in.html

Comment: Would this consume resources from the machine running the browser, or from the server?

Comment: This Javascript would run in the browser, not the server.